# Adding a button to a cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In Navigation Bar you get a Arrow shaped Back button similar to this [image](http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-04-29/tcodizkisriixnluwoCkxjCacwFdziutEjGIwDJvsAClGBjtebnuaIdEuujn/Screen_shot_2011-04-29_at_22.53.29.png.scaled500.png). (According to this image the arrow is named `folders`)

I need to add this Arrow shaped bar button on to a cell. Is this possible ? How can i do this programatically ?

Comment: Do you mean a cell in a table view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The navigation controller back button (with the arrow appearance) can only be added using code to a navigation bar - by setting the back bar button property of the navigation item of the previous controller in the stack.

You can't add this button to a table cell, and frankly it would look a little odd - what does it do? Does each cell go "back" to a different screen? Apple aren't usually keen on you repurposing existing UI elements to mean something other than the standard.

There is no built in UIButton or UIBarButtonItem that will give you that appearance, therefore you will have to create your own image and use that as the background for a custom button which you can then add to your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a custom button and can set background as an image which is arrow shaped.

if you are using navigation controller-

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Folders" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBack target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
[myViewController release];
```

Comment: I don't want to add an image to make it look like a Navigation back button. I need the navigation back button (as shown in the image) to be added to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can take custom table cell to prepare table view. In that custom table cell you will be able to add button and `IBaction.` You can take help from this [tutorial](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284) on how to create `UITableCell` and then `UITableView`.

Comment: I know how to add a button, but what i want to add is a Navigation button to the cell.

Comment: @ZubairRaihan now that is a funky method name you mention in you comment - :D -